# How is wsdl file generated in jaxws

Tags: jax-ws

I have an webservice with the interface and implementation class. I export he app as war and deploy to tomcat. How and when is the wsdl file generated for the services???

Inreface:
@WebService(name = "StoreSurveyAuth")
public interface SurveyAuthorization {

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name="AuthorizationResponse")
public AuthorizationResponse getAuthorizationDetails(SurveyAuthRequest surveyAuthRequest);
```

Impl Class:

@WebService(serviceName = "AuthService", endpointInterface = "com.test.SurveyAuthorization")
public class SurveyAuthorizationImpl implements SurveyAuthorization {

}

I have also provided the url in web.xml and the endpoint is defined in sun-jaxws.xml.
But the wsdl is not generated when I deplot in tomcat.

Comment: You say the WSDL is not being generated. How do you know this? What are you specifically expecting to happen, and what does happen or doesn't happen?

Comment: after deploying the app. i try to validate my soap webservice. So i hit the wsdl location which should have been generated.I have followed as http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/ , http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/

Comment: So you visit the URL that you think will return the WSDL, and you don't get a WSDL. What do you get instead? Are there any errors in the tomcat log from deployment or when you request the WSDL?

Comment: I get a blank page with no errors in server http:{serverdetails }/SFOD-WS/storesurveytemplate?wsdl